Powers of terms in bracket expressions
in book "perspectives on projective geometry" chapter 18.8, I have come across some terminology I don't understand.

What does the author mean by "power" here and why does the mentioned frequency imply projective invariance?
Also,

I don't understand the above reasoning for the previous reason.
Could anyone please explain to me what I am missing here? How is the conic a circle?
Thank you.

In the expression $\frac{(3xy)(12y^2z)}{(y^3(4xz)}$, the numerator, when written out, has $y$ to the third power; so does the denominator. The same applies to $x$ and $z$: their 'total exponent' in the numerator is the same as in the denominator. So that answers the first question ("power"). Now suppose that you multiply each of $x, y,$ and $z$ by $3.7$. The $y^3$ in the numerator becomes $3.7^3 y^3$ ... and the same thing happens in the denominator, so the $3.7^3$s cancel. The same for $x$ and $z$; the overall quotient remains unchanged. That's 'projective invariance'.
